# how to make thumbnail from a .swf in php?

Tags: php, flash

I have to make thumbnails from banners in swf file format (flash 9). I want to use php, but if that's not possible anything which work in a linux command line is fine by me.

I tried to open them with ffmpeg-php, but it says: Can't open movie file /where/the/file/is

The file is there and is readable by the user.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain this `ls -1 /where/the/file/is` return anything?

Comment: sure, its there, i can open it from browser, etc.

Comment: lengyel - Open from browser is different from in the server path. `Normally open from browser = document root + path`, which you use the same for your ffmpeg command. **PS** stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: and i'm well aware of the difference between the paths, thanks.the browser part was to suggest: yes, the file is real, yes, i can see, it's the correct one, and yes the webserver has the rigth to open it. just to avoid another round of useless comments.